# Show test results with TFS Build

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tfs, nunit

All!
We are trying to setup our TFS 2013 to daily builds. 
And we have some legacy CostomBuild.target script which run all our build/deploy/test processes. So for build and deploy - it's work fine. We are able run this processes with RunMsBuild step. But our customer would like to see TFS-like results of testing. It means that instead of running of the tests with VS test runner we have to run this test with this CostomBuild.target. This script will run nunit console and will produce test results. And this test results we have to show as results of testing in TFS. How could we do that?
I know the location of nunit test results, but how can I show them in TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have received the test results in a .trx file, you can use the TCM utility to publish them. See this thread

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cbf10f4f-9751-4f69-a6cb-f27ac78ade0b/publishing-test-results-to-build-after-running-manual-test-in-ms-test-manager?forum=vsmantest

Comment: Hi. Thanks for responce. Here is one problem. Thnks for notice about .trx. I had no idea about this files. I will use article http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/07/19/integrate-nunit-test-into-a-tfs-build/ to convert my xml to trx and after will integrate this into tfs build. Thanks